# Adding title tag on check box select and .html() value

Tags: jquery, checkbox, checkboxlist

[image: The html code with elements]

i need to add the 'title' and its text as highlighted on selection of a checkbox...

i have written the following jquery to do iy but it doesnt seem to be working.

```
              $('.ddcl-ddlPresentingIssue').closest('.ui-dropdownchecklist-text').html('Hello');
              $('.ddcl-ddlPresentingIssue').closest('.ui-dropdownchecklist-text').attr("title", 'Helo');
```

but it doesnt set the value in html and title tag.. then i tried the same with this way..

```
$('.ddcl-ddlPresentingIssue .ui-dropdownchecklist-text').html('Hello');
$('.ddcl-ddlPresentingIssue .ui-dropdownchecklist-text').attr("title", 'Helo');
```

Even still it doesnt work. i am wondering what would be wrong here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the selectors. In Jquery # is used for ids

The selector thus becomes

```
$('#ddcl-ddlPresentingIssue .ui-dropdownchecklist-text').html('Hello').attr('title','Helo');
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `#` in place of `.` in your second attempt  like this-

```
$('#ddcl-ddlPresentingIssue .ui-dropdownchecklist-text').html('Hello');
```

As `ddcl-ddlPresentingIssue` being an ID

---

Your first example would work if you use `find()` instead of `closest()` and `#` in place of `.`

```
$('#ddcl-ddlPresentingIssue').find('.ui-dropdownchecklist-text').html('Hello');
```

Comment: tnx a lot. my bad, i missed the # :-|

Answer (score 1):

Use `#ddcl-ddlPresentingIssue` as it is id as shown in the image.

make use `#` for id selector and `.` for the class selector.

```
 $('#ddcl-ddlPresentingIssue').closest('.ui-dropdownchecklist-text').html('Hello');
```

Answer (score 1):

You've used a wrong selector: `ddcl-ddlPresentingIssue` is the ID on the span.

In jQuery and CSS you use `#` for IDs and `.` for classes.

```
$('#ddcl-ddlPresentingIssue .ui-dropdownchecklist-text').html('Hello');
$('#ddcl-ddlPresentingIssue .ui-dropdownchecklist-text').attr("title", 'Helo');
```